Quarto revealjs presentation: image layout with layout-nrow=2 does not fit on slide
I cannot figure out how to make a Quarto RevealJS presentation with a layout of multiple images in a grid fit onto the slide. I have tried many different arguments in the pandoc div attributes as well as resizing the individual images but no matter what, the sizes of the images do not change in the rendered HTML. The bottom row does not fit in the slide dimensions. I have not found the solution in GitHub issues that appear to be related, such as https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2251.
Example quarto document
---
title: "Test"
format: revealjs
---

## Bayes

::: {layout-nrow=2}

![](https://usda-ree-ars.github.io/SEAStats/images/Thomas_Bayes.gif)

![](https://usda-ree-ars.github.io/SEAStats/images/Thomas_Bayes.gif)

![](https://usda-ree-ars.github.io/SEAStats/images/Thomas_Bayes.gif)

![](https://usda-ree-ars.github.io/SEAStats/images/Thomas_Bayes.gif)

![](https://usda-ree-ars.github.io/SEAStats/images/Thomas_Bayes.gif)

![](https://usda-ree-ars.github.io/SEAStats/images/Thomas_Bayes.gif)

:::

Appearance of rendered html
You can see that the layout of six images does not fit on the slide.


I found a workaround using ::: {.columns}, creating three columns, and setting the size of each image individually. But I would still be interested in what is possible with layout-nrow
